# check if not undefined always evaluates to true

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript

```
 var array = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var newArray = [];
    array.forEach(function(entry) {
        if (entry.description != undefined) {
            newArray.push(entry);
        }
    });
```

I have an array filled with objects where some has a description and some does not - and I would like to filter out those that do not.

My problem is that the if-statement always evaluates to true no matter if description is undefined or not

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot - entry.description is undefined, but it still pushes it to the array.

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

It seems to be working as intended with original code - after a firefox restart :S
I believe it might have been a firefox debugger issue.
Thank you all for you help anyway - feel free to comment on the actual code piece if you have anything to add though

Comment: Most likely nothing - do you have a sample array for this case? Also, you're implementing a crude `Array.prototype.filter` with your `newArray` and `forEach` - consider just using that instead.

Comment: I have to ask, just to be sure: is your global undefined variable still undefined?:)

Comment: @Sacho use what instead?
undefined is part of ecmascript.js - but yes :) 
seems to be working now - I think it was a firefox debugger problem - not showing correct data

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a typo, but the code you posted uses `!==` while the image shows `!=`

Comment: @VisualBean Use `Array.prototype.filter` instead of `forEach` and pushing to a `newArray` - e.g. `return array.filter(function (entry) { return entry.description !== undefined })`. I don't think your problem is related to the comparison, that's why I asked for a sample array of data to try out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
if ( typeof entry.description != "undefined" ) {
   //code if not undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `hasOwnProperty`

```
if(entry.hasOwnProperty("description ")){
  //you code
}
```